# Why do we need the triangle inequality for a probability distance measures?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Kullback Leibler Divergence measure does not satisfy the triangle inequality. But the Hellinger Distance does. Do we really need triangle inequality for a probability distance measure? What does it buy us and where do we use it?

In my applications, I usually have a probability density function that is also a function of some parameters like $p(x|\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the parameter. I have to minimize the function $D(p_0(x)||p(x|\theta))$ with respect to the variable $\theta$. $p_0(x)$ is a known or desired probability density function.  The measure $D(p||q)$ is any distance/divergence measure between any two pdfs $p$ and $q$.

Does having triangle inequality for $D$ (like Hellinger distance) make the numerical optimization procedure better?